# Why is my code not working the way I expect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using Javascript to change an HTML element. I change the innerText AND I am trying to change the class.
The innerText changes... but the class "beautiful" is NOT applied to the element with Id "top". 
Why not ?

I have checked if the function is called. It obviously is... since the innerText IS changed.

```js
function beautify(){ 
   item = document.getElementById("top");
   item.classList.add = "beautiful";
   item.innerText = "Why does it not work ?";
   return;
}
```

```css
.beautiful{
   color: blue;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-family: helvetica;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="top">I'm going to change</h1>
<button onclick="beautify()"  >Click here for a special effect</button>
```

I was expecting the button to change not only the innerText, but also to add styling in the shape of adding the class "beautiful" to the element with id "top".

Comment: Look up the docs for `classList`. `item.classList.add =` is not the right syntax

Comment: It should be `item.classList.add('<your-class-name>')`. `add` is a method, not a getter/setter.

Comment: @xmastertje - Probably none, assigning to the method is valid syntax. ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder fair enough ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this way

```
item.classList.add("beautiful"); // correct way to add new class using javascript
```

instead of

```
 item.classList.add = "beautiful";
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there! `item.classlist.add` is not a getter/setter, but a method. So in order to add a class to the element you need to call it like this:
`item.classList.add('your-class-here');`

Comment: Thanks so much :-)   I feel silly, but the way you formulated your answer is really encouraging !   Makes me feel like I'm LEARNING in stead of being stupid :-)

Comment: Don't you ever feel stupid when you're learning! Everyone started from the bottom and you should be proud of yourself trying to get better. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method `add` on `classList`:

```js
function beautify(){ 
   item = document.getElementById("top");
   item.classList.add("beautiful");
   item.innerText = "Now it works as expected!";
   return;
}
```

```css
.beautiful{
   color: blue;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-family: helvetica;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="top">I'm going to change</h1>
<button onclick="beautify()"  >Click here for a special effect</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .beautiful{
                color: blue;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-family: helvetica;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function beautify(){    
                item = document.getElementById("top");
                item.className = "beautiful";
                item.innerText = "Why does it not work ?";
                return;
        }
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <h1 id="top">I'm going to change</h1>
        <button onclick="beautify()"  >Click here for a special effect</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

this should work.

Comment: @AlexvanWinkel Now its your turn to mark it as Answer. Vote up!

Comment: Yes.. I just did :-)  
Sorry I'm still learning how the StackOverflow system works.. but I'm getting the hang of it  !

Comment: No worries @AlexvanWinkel :)